# Wrong POST Data parse in PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, post

I just have a very strange behaviour of HTTP POST method in php. 
An example below:

I create a file named post.php

```
// post.php
<?php 
    print_r($_POST);
    exit;
?>
```

And sending some data to this page via curl:

```
curl 'http://example.com/post.php' --data 'test=test2'
```

it returns:

```
Array
(
    [test] => test2test=test2
)
```

In case i send data with 2 or more keys:

```
curl 'http://example.com/post.php' --data 'test=test2' --data 't=1'
```

it returns:

```
Array
(
    [test] => test2
    [t] => 1
)
```

This problem arose after php upgrading.

```
Environment:
PHP - PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u5
OS - Debian 6.0.3 64bit
```

Does anybody faced with problem like that?

Comment: Unable to reproduce on php 5.9, deb 6.

Comment: What does it say if u add `--dump-header headers` also try removing the single quotes `'` from the URL and putting the parameters always before the URL leaving the URL as last parameter. I am not entirely sure but isn't the default method `GET` so you should also have `-X POST`?

Comment: Prix, issue reproduces not only via curl, bit with submitting a form as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was fixed after upgrading up to PHP 5.4.25-1